# Convert 2015-06-01T02:31:00+0000 to DateTime object c#

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime, utc

I'm writting an app that consume this webservice:

http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json

as you can see there, the JSON object comes with an utc datetime field. I want to save this information in a simple DateTime object with the following format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

This is my code:

```
 DateTime dateParsed = DateTime.Now;       
 DateTime.TryParseExact((string)resource.SelectToken("resource").SelectToken("fields")["utctime"], "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dateParsed);
```

I'm getting an DateTime object initialized in the year 0001.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to parse the string using standard DateTime.TryParse(), store the value in Database as DateTime type and upon necessity to display it using any formatting spec you need. Best regards,

Comment: if you look at the DateTime definition "Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001.", the question is does your TryParseExact parse the correct date and time fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just an error in your Format-String. This is a working sample:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dateParsed = DateTime.Now; 
        if ( DateTime.TryParseExact( "2015-06-01T02:31:00+0000", "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dateParsed ) ) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parsing done: {0:MM/dd/yyyy @ hh:mm}", dateParsed ) );
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("No result");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the `+0000` is hardcoded, when you get other values you would need to detect them. If the api returns only +0 values, you could cut them off and work without z.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using [the `K` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier) (instead of `z`).

```
string s = "2015-06-01T04:41:10+0000";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

It will read the `+0000` as the offset.  Then by using the `AdjustToUniversal` style, the resulting `DateTime` will *also* be in terms of Universal time, having `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Also, since you're reading from a known data source, there's no real benefit of using `TryParseExact`.  The format from your data source is fixed, so just use `ParseExact` with that format.  The `Try...` methods are primarily for validating user input, or when the source format could vary.

One last point - if you just parse your data using [JSON.net](http://json.net), that format should automatically be recognized.  You just use a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` property, and it would parse it without issue.